# Render swiftui NavigationLink on the bottom of the screen (and not on the side) on MacOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

Got this simple `swiftui` NavigationView example. Works fine, but is there anyway to have the List on the top half of the window en the "destination" on the bottom half of the window?

I was looking for some modifiers, but getting the impression this only works with one half (the List) on the left and the destination one on the right side of the window?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination 1")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Col 1")
                        Text("Col 2")
                        Text("Col 3")
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination 2")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Col 1")
                        Text("Col 2")
                        Text("Col 3")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely not built in